# How to interpolate user interests

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I have a database of users with one field describing their interests in form of an array of strings. I'd like to write an algorithm which is able to take as input the list of users and returns groups of users with the same interests. The end goal would be to suggest the users what they may be interested into based on what users with similar interests are interested into. Could anybody suggest an algorithm that I could implement to achieve such result?

Thank you.

Comment: "You may also like..." algorithms are a hard problem. Hard enough that Netflix was [willing to pay a million dollars](http://www.netflixprize.com/) to get a marginal improvement over their existing approach.

Comment: I see. I know this is a hard problem, I reduced the input space and (hopefully) the output space enough to get some suggestions about the algorithm to use. I've took a look at interpolation algorithms but I can't figure how to map my input space on a 2D plane to apply the said algorithms.

Comment: How many users do you have? How many interests can they each enter? How many different interests are there in total? (roughly)

Comment: I'd say 400k users tops, interests should be around 30/40 in total, and users may be interested in everything, even though that's unlikely. I'd say a rough estimate of the average number of interests may be around 10 to 15, 20 tops.

Comment: With the total number of interests being limited, and each user simply being yes/no interested in each of them, have you thought about storing the interests for each user as a bit pattern? XOR'ing two users' interests would tell you the level of agreement.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. I will refine it and see if that leads me somewhere. Thanks for the suggestion, buddy!